# What is the better way to load a page in Iframe vs $(div).load?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have multiple pages in my MVC5 project, So, What is the better way to load a page in Iframe vs $(div).load?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience,

- `Iframe` is counted as whole page. This means, your page will have loading status when your iframe is loading. That is very annoying for several user include me.
- On the other side, `$(div).load` is very customizable because you got every javascript backup your page. Besides you can load it latter when page is done loading. And if you do like this, you wont get loading status circling on page tab.